# How to create my own DAW

Tags: audio

I am studying Discrete Mathematics and am a passionate musician. I would like to create a simple DAW for my final-year university project. (I would like it to have the ability to record and edit several tracks.)

I have searched Google for suggestions for starting out with making my own DAW, but have found very little that seems helpful.

I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870740/creating-a-digital-audio-workstation), however.

I recently came across Sound Design and thought it would be apt to ask for help here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question belongs on a programming site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: @DoritoStyle Alright. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether you're asking about the software & development environment necessary to write audio processing tools yourself or whether you're asking about the hardware required for installing ready-made tools for composition and sound engineering.

Comment: On the music side; Maybe you should start off with something smaller. a DAW is a complete suite of tools. Maybe you should ignore some tools. Like make an audio recorder/sequencer and mixer instead, or a VST Effects handler... or a MIDI sequencer ...etc.

Comment: I think creating a DAW won't be such a good choice of FYP. IMO it would be much better to concentrate on a smaller chuck of functionality, and do it really well. This'll have the benefit of producing something worth demo'ing and also something that has potential to turn into a product later-on. Source: I made this mistake with my FYP!

Comment: @Paul My initial project idea was to learn how to create a simple version of the software environment necessary for editing audio (a very simple version of a popular DAW such as FL Studio [or Logic], for example).

Comment: @MarcW That is extremely helpful. Thank you. I didn't realise that a DAW is made up of such a suite of tools.

Comment: @SimonBosley The advice is much appreciated.

Comment: @COY I hope I didn't kill the dream! I just started learning JUCE, a great open platform library for creating music applications and plug-ins. I think that would be a great place to start, and many professional audio companies are using it too.

Comment: I think this is what Simon is referring to: [JUCE](https://www.juce.com/discover).